# Import e-mails from old account in Kloxo

Tags: email

Good morning everyone. Our client has moved their domain to another server we provide (moved from VM to dedicated). Can anybody advise me on how to import the client's e-mails from the previous IP address (the VM had)? The client has the same e-mail address that he used to have before moving to dedicated server. We use Kloxo control Panel and the client used Roundcube web mail to access their e-mails. Thanx in advance!

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import emails in kloxo here is the folder, you just need to copy them (I think)

**/home/lxadmin/mail/domains/"domain.name"/"email"/Maildir**

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by admitting I've never even heard of Kloxo, but my **general** solution to "how do I bulk-migrate mail from server A to server B" is to find out if both source and destination servers support IMAP, then use an IMAP client that deals well with bulk operations - personally, I prefer [alpine](http://www.washington.edu/alpine/) - and bulk-copy the contents, one folder at a time, from source to destination.

If I had a really large number of folders to move, I suspect there exist PERL scripts for this sort of thing, which again do it via IMAP; but I've never yet had a need for that

IMAP's a well-understood and well-implemented standard, and using a protocol-based method lets you sidestep round questions of internal storage format, indexing, and so on, as each server will provide that for itself.

Comment: Actually kloxo users qmail as a mail server, if this makes it more specific.

Comment: No, but it opens up the common misunderstanding that there's such a thing as "a mail server", one fostered (imho) by exchange.  In most implementations, the *sending* of mail out, and the *reading* of mail in, are two completely different functions, handled by at least two different daemons.  The former, which implements the SMTP protocol, is known as a Mail Transport Agent (MTA); qmail is one such.  The latter, which implements IMAP and/or the POP protocols, are known as IMAP/POP daemons (though often an IMAP daemon will do POP for free, as it were); I'm interested in what you have there.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer was much simpler than i expected. I just had to copy (using the scp command) the files from the mail directory of the old server to the respective mail directory of the new one, which by the way for a kloxo control panel is:

/home/lxadmin/mail/domains/[client's_domain]/[clients e-mail]/Maildir/cur